# Integrate wordpress before hosting

Tags: hosting, customization

My website isn't hosted yet - it's just a collection of html and css in a folder, right now.

Will I be able to integrate a wordpress blog into this before hosting, or does the site need to be hosted before I can integrate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[WordPress requires PHP & MySQL](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) (and `mod_rewrite` or equivalent is very helpful to have, too), so if you're running those on the machine where your unhosted website currently resides, you can run WordPress. If you're not, you can't.

You can install PHP and MySQL to run locally on just about any OS you can name -- I've got them running on my Windows desktop machine and my desktop & laptop Linux installations. See, for example, [XAMPP](https://www.google.com/search?q=xampp).